# Trying to initialize members in a class by calling variable from outside function

Tags: python, function, class, init

Hello I am working on an assignment and I am trying to call a value that I inputted into a function before making the class. What is it I am doing wrong. Or is this even something that is possible.

```
def main():
    size = int(input()) 

class Ant:

    def __init__(self):
        self._size = (size??) 

    def get_size(self):
        return self._size

main()

ant_1 = Ant()

print(ant_1.get_size())
```

Comment: The variable "size" is local to the function "main" and vanishes at the end of execution. Declare it explicitly as "global".

Comment: Why don't you just add `size` to `Ant` and send it as a parameter to `__init__`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher better yet, return the value explicitly from main.

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned by @Michael, `size` is a local variable within the scope of `main` function. You need to define it `global` to access it any where:

```
def main():
    global size
    size = int(input())
```

However, `global` variables are bad, so you can return the value, add the parameter `size` to `__init__()` and pass the returned value:

```
def main():
    size = int(input()) 
    return size
class Ant:

    def __init__(self,size):
        self._size = (size) 

    def get_size(self):
        return self._size

size=main()
ant_1 = Ant(size)
print(ant_1.get_size())
```

Comment: So we haven’t learned the global thing yet so I doubt I can use it. Thanks for your response. But I’m still a little confused because their are actually multiple values like position and orientation that are supposed to be under main. And those inputs need to somehow be called to the init in the ant class. Not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the `size` to your `Ant` constructor:

```py
class Ant:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self._size = size

    def get_size(self):
        return self._size
```

then your `main` would look something like this:

```py
def main():
    size = int(input())
    my_ant = Ant(size)
    print(my_ant.get_size())
```